Which format is the result of 'fail2ban-client banned' command and how I can fully load the result in PHP (as array)
This is the format of the data returned by command fail2ban-client banned:
[{'sshd': []}, {'nginx-http-auth': []}, {'nginx-botsearch': []}, {'recidive': []}, {'wo-wordpress': []}, {'nginx-forbidden': ['45.147.96.37']}, {'vm-malware': ['28.59.248.171', '89.105.11.189']}]

What's the type of the format? It's not json, is it? Something with python?
Most of all, how I can load it into PHP as array? (some elegant way).
Man page mentions some "dictionary". I did not get it.
Thank you.

AFAIK, you should be able to replace the single quotes with double quotes and then parse it as JSON. I don't know if that's true for every Python dictionary, but it does work with this sample: https://3v4l.org/Ih6qU#v8.3.9. Once you do that, you should be able to loop over it as you see fit

What @ChrisHaas suggests should work as long as none of the keys contain literal quotes.

@ChrisHaas yes, you are right. Suggested code works. If you will write answer I will accept it. What the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR practically does, I did not get it from the doc. Thank you.

@JasomDotnet, because there's some extra looping involved to reduce this a bit beyond what I wrote, I'm okay with you writing an answer. As it stands, what I provided is still a little ugly. As to the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, if you don't include it then json_encode will return null if there's an error, and you need to manually call json_last_error_msg or json_last_error to find out what happened. A lot of people would recommend letting the exception shout loudly instead of failing silently, possibly introducing a bug later.

The code @ChrisHaas suggested solved the question:
$data = <<<EOT
[{'sshd': []}, {'nginx-http-auth': []}, {'nginx-botsearch': []}, {'recidive': []}, {'wo-wordpress': []}, {'nginx-forbidden': ['45.147.96.37']}, {'vm-malware': ['28.59.248.171', '89.105.11.189']}]
EOT;


$jails = json_decode(str_replace("'", '"', $data), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

var_dump($jails);

You may be curious what the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR does. The Answer is:

...if you don't include it then json_encode will return null if there's an error, and you need to manually call json_last_error_msg or json_last_error to find out what happened. A lot of people would recommend letting the exception shout loudly instead of failing silently, possibly introducing a bug later.

Thank you Chris to solving the problem.
